# Why this sqlite3 code in PYTHON 3.7 program about employees and their first name,last name and salaries is not getting printed in the output?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, python-3.7

I have a sqlite3 program in which I have to connect to a database stored in 'employees.db'. I will enter the first name, last name and salary and then print it. For printing, I will use fetchall(). But when I print the output, what I get is this-->

```
[]
```

only 2 square brackets?
What is wrong?

I have started to learn python 2 weeks ago. But my course where I am learning is going too fast. I don't know what I am doing in this program is the correct approach or not?

---

## HERE IS MY CODE--->>>

```
import sqlite3;


conn=sqlite3.connect('employees.db');
c=conn.cursor();


c.execute("""CREATE TABLE employees(first text,last text,pay integer)""");


c.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Tendo','Sinha',600000)");
c.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Krit','Kumar',40000)");



print(c.fetchall());



conn.commit();
conn.close
```

---

I don't get any error. The output only shows:-

```
[]
```

Only 2 square brackets.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help but all insert statements I've seen specify the columns. `c.execute("INSERT INTO employees (first, last, pay) VALUES('Tendo','Sinha',600000)");`

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting rows into the table but not retrieving them at all.

Try adding a `SELECT` statement:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("employees.db")
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table, insert things...
c.execute(
    """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees(first text,last text,pay integer)"""
)
c.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Kritin','Sinha',600000)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Krit','Kumar',40000)")

# Commit the changes.
conn.commit()

# Retrieve from the table.
c.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
print(c.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to run a query for fetching all rows.

add these lines to your code-

```
data = c.execute("Select * FROM employees").fetchall()

print(data);
```